# Regex Replace For Wordpress Shortcodes

Tags: regex, wordpress, replace

I have a wordpress site with a ton of posts with the following kind of markup:

```
<div class="comments container">[song_comments song_slug="this time"]</div>
```

I want a regex search/replace pattern which will search for any string like

```
<div class="comments container">[song_comments XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
```

...and replace it with an empty string.

So the left delimiter is

```
<div class="comments container">[song_comments
```

...and the right delimiter is

```
</div>
```

With everything between being variable.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You want to remove the whole div or just `[.........` part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$html = preg_replace(
    '~<div class=["\']comments container["\']>\[song_comments[^<]++</div>~',
    '', $html);
```

If you are interested by:

[preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

[www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info)

Comment: THANKS! One of those skills---like card tricks, I keep meaning to master in order to dazzle people like me.

What usually gets me stumped are special characters like brackets and hairpins. Gotta study this. I only need it once in a great while, but when I need it... I NEED it.  Big cheers!